# Does julia have an equivalent function to hstack in python?

Tags: julia

I would like to construct a 2d array of size n x d using d columns vectors of length n.

Does julia have such a function or something similar?

Comment: `hcat`, (see also `vcat` and `hvcat`)

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have 2 columns:

```
julia> columns = [rand(1:20,3) for _ in 1:2]
2-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 [20, 3, 19]
 [9, 11, 18]
```

`hcat` does the job taking each column:

```
julia> hcat(columns[1], columns[2])
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 20   9
  3  11
 19  18
```

You can also just pass the entire vector using `...` operator:

```
julia> hcat(columns...)
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 20   9
  3  11
 19  18
```

The Matrix syntax also supports building one from columns:

```
julia> [columns[1] columns[2]]
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 20   9
  3  11
 19  18
```